# What is the best way to sort a Django queryset by group?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following model for events:

```
class EventStatus(models.TextChoices):
    Open = "Open"
    Closed = "Closed"
    Completed = "Completed"
    Archived = "Archived"

class Marketplace(models.Model):
    Creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Speaking_Event_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Topic = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=EventStatus.choices, default=EventStatus.Open)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Speaking_Event_Name

    def status(self):
        return EventStatus.Completed if timezone.now() > self.date else self.Status
```

and I also have the following view function to show the list of events by a user:

```
def view_events(request):
    event_list = Marketplace.objects.filter(Creator=current_user)
    content = {'events': event_list}
    return render(request, 'view_events.html', content)
```

I would like to know how to sort the events list in order by Status, where all the "Open" events are listed first, then "Closed" second, "Completed" third and "Archived" listed last.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate with a priority based on the choices:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When


def view_events(request):
    event_list = (
        Marketplace.objects.filter(Creator=current_user)
        .alias(
            priority=Case(
                *[When(Status=status, then=Value(i)) for i, status in EventStatus]
            )
        )
        .order_by('priority')
    )
    return render(request, 'view_events.html', {'events': event_list})
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `creator` instead of <s>`Creator`</s>.

Comment: Do I have to import anything to use Case and When?

Comment: @yuriyu: yes, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

Comment: I imported the libraries and I tried printing event_list but it's not returning anything

Comment: @yuriyu: you passed it to the template as `events`, not `event_list`...

Comment: I know, but when I added a print(event_list) line underneath it still doesn't return anything

Comment: @yuriyu: I made a typo.

Comment: Still didn't work for me, still returned nothing

Comment: @yuriyu: is there any exception? Are you sure there are any records in the db for that user?

Comment: Marketplace.objects.filter(Creator=current_user) does work. It does return a list of records for a certain user. It's just that it seems to not recognise `alias()` as a django function. Do I need to import alias?

Comment: @yuriyu: no, if you use an old version, you need to use `.annotate(..)` instead of `.alias(..)`.